# Why we say “thank you very much” after good news

Tags: idioms-in-context

I have heard many times in movies when they share good news, like a woman got promoted, she says when telling her friends about the promotion:

> I'm now the head of the department, thank you very much.

while of course they had nothing to do with her promotion they were not behind it. Why would she said thank you?

Another situation I also saw in a movie was a girl telling her friend that she got engaged then said about the groom

> He is a doctor, thank you very much.

Again, why did she say thank you? I don't understand what it means.
please explain for me.

Comment: You can add 'thank you very much' to an announcement of good news to signify that you are boasting or expressing happiness.

Comment: See the third definition [here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/thank+you+very+much).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes I agree it's adding some boastful emphasis to the preceding statement. In films and plays you often see it accompanied by a sort of flounce by the speaker. The whole phrase "thankyou very much" often has the meaning, "look at me, aren't I lucky" Although in other similar contexts the meaning could be different, omitting it shouldn't change the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: luna - you should be able to tell from the intonation of *[I had success in something that didn't involve you] **...thank you very much*** that the final words are facetious, not intended literally. The more common alternative phrasing in such contexts is usually ***- no thanks to you**!* (which ***is*** intended literally - speaker is making the point that others either failed to help or even actively *hindered* the process).

Comment: I feel like there's another possible explanation: someone facetiously accepting congratulations that have not yet (or will not) come. "I got a promotion today, thank you very much, hold your applause." So much of how this is interpreted depends on the context and the tone of the speaker.

Answer (score 2):

It's common to use "thank you" sarcastically to denote that either (i) someone has given you something you didn't want and you don't really feel thankful, or (ii) that someone has failed to help you and doesn't deserve your thanks. But sarcasm means saying something *insincerely*, often saying the opposite of what you mean, and that doesn't seem to be the case with your example.

It's also quite common, in all sincerity and politeness, to say thank you *in advance* or *in anticipation* of something you have asked for. Sometimes, we may say 'thank you' to make an authoritative request sound more polite. For example, a parent or teacher might tell a child "*don't do that, thank you*" to sound firmer than "*please don't do that*", which sounds more like a polite request. Similarly, someone might use the same language to assert their authority in a workplace. For example, a person might remind a subordinate of their title/position in a company by saying "*I'm the manager, thank you very much*" which essentially means "*I thank you not to forget that I'm the manager*". Your example sounds like it may be a more playful version of this said between friends as a joke about their new authority.

Answer (score 1):

McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions includes this entry:

> **thank you very much** *phr.*
> a (sometimes sarcastic) tag added to a statement for emphasis. (Often used when there is really nothing to thank anyone for.)
> *I will manage somehow to find my own way out, thank you very much.*

In both your examples, the emphasis shows how proud the speakers are.

The same expression can also be used to indicate that someone has said or done something wrong:

> *(a tourist to a local)* I'm Canadian, not American, thank you very much!
> *(a teacher to a student using a cell phone)* You'll stay off your cell phone in class, thank you very much!

NOTE: In pretty much all contexts, the phrase comes off negatively. In your two examples, it sounds like bragging. In my first example, it's a passive-aggressive claim of offence at nothing serious. In my second example, the teacher is being unnecessarily rude.

If someone is simply correcting someone else, they might use "***Actually,** I'm Canadian*" or "***Close,** I'm Canadian*". If someone is actually offended by the mistake (as opposed to *claiming offence* in order to put someone else down), they would show it in a different way.